# Test Data for Time and Date Parsing (Varied Formats)

Tags: datetime, testing, formatting

Any ideas how I can get a varied set of time / date strings to test a parser?

The idea is to see how wide a range of different *formats* can be parsed.  Note that I am looking for different formats, so simply extracting all timestamps from a bunch of emails isn't that useful (since the format is fixed by RFC 2822).

[Also, I am not sure this is appropriate for SO, sorry, so please feel free to suggest an alternative place to ask.]

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to create your own list.  But here are some resources describing some of the various formats you might encounter:

- http://www.hackcraft.net/web/datetime/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country